# Why does the "keypress" event handler not fire consistently?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a problem with this function. I cannot get it to fire properly. It does work, but  when I highlight the quantity in the form and change the value (the value is initially set to 1), my stock level is 20, when I type in 21 it won't display the message unless I press another key.  What am I doing wrong?  I have tried every event possible, and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. BTW, this is in a jQuery UI dialog box.

```
$('#qty').live('keypress', function() {
  $('#response').hide();
  if($('#qty').val() > stockLevel) {
    var response = 'You selected more than we have in stock, we have reset your quantity to the maximum number available in stock';
    $('#qty').val(stockLevel);
    $('#response').html(response).show('blind', {}, '200'); 
    return false;
 }
});
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Have you tried keyup instead of keypress?

Comment: Maybe this is just an example, but this sort of validation needs to occur server side.

Comment: I will double-check it on the server when the order is submitted, but I want to eliminate as many errors before they occur, and provide a smoother user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keypress event has notoriously inconsistent behavior (because it is not defined in any standards). In your case your event is firing before the browser puts the text into the textbox. Use the keyup event instead.

Comment: Tried Keyup, seemed to have better results.  Only thing is, say the value of stockLevel is 20, when I clear the qty box and type just 3 it shows the message?  Strange?  Also, I will double check it on the server side, but want to eliminate as many issues ahead of time before they are submitted.

Comment: Do I need to convert the value of stockLevel to an integer?

Comment: Think I figured it out.  User parseFloat(stockLevel) and that seemed to make the results work perfectly.